# Outlook Exchange Office 365: How to get email address from access token?

Tags: c#, outlook, oauth-2.0, office365, access-token

Currently, I am following this article https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/dotnet . Everything works great expect I cannot retrieve the user's email address from acess-token.

```
 private string GetEmailFromIdToken(string token) {
        // JWT is made of three parts, separated by a '.' 
        // First part is the header 
        // Second part is the token 
        // Third part is the signature 
        string[] tokenParts = token.Split('.');
        if (tokenParts.Length < 3) {
            // Invalid token, return empty
        }
        // Token content is in the second part, in urlsafe base64
        string encodedToken = tokenParts[1];
        // Convert from urlsafe and add padding if needed
        int leftovers = encodedToken.Length % 4;
        if (leftovers == 2) {
            encodedToken += "==";
        } else if (leftovers == 3) {
            encodedToken += "=";
        }
        encodedToken = encodedToken.Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/');
        // Decode the string
        var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(encodedToken);
        string decodedToken = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
        // Load the decoded JSON into a dynamic object
        dynamic jwt = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(decodedToken);
        // User's email is in the preferred_username field
        return jwt.preferred_username;
    }
```

In some article people says to add "openid"

```
 private static string[] scopes = { "openid", "https://outlook.office.com/mail.read",
                                   "https://outlook.office.com/calendars.read" };
```

in the scope. However it still doesn't work. It doesn't even give a successful login, throws exception. 
When I don't add the "openid", I get a successful login however preferred_username is empty.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good catch!

You need to include the "profile" scope in order to read the preferred_username,

```
private static string[] scopes = { "profile",
                                       "https://outlook.office.com/mail.read",
                                       "https://outlook.office.com/calendars.read" };
```

Alternatively, try using the "contacts.read" scope

```
private static string[] scopes = { "https://outlook.office.com/contacts.read",
                                       "https://outlook.office.com/mail.read",
                                       "https://outlook.office.com/calendars.read" };
```

Find out more on the permission scopes in https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/content/authorization/permission_scopes.md

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, yes now it is giving the email but token is now empty. How to get both token and email address.  +1 .. Thank you again for your reply

Comment: which token are you referring to?

Comment: var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                    authCode, onSuccessRedirectUri, credential, scopes);
                var outlookToken = new OutlookToken();
                // Save the token in the session
                outlookToken.Token = authResult.Token;

Comment: We can also add "email" in the scope add that

Answer (score 1):

I've seen some cases where the `preferred_username` claim isn't an SMTP address, so it's actually not the best way to get the user's email address. I'd recommend instead of parsing the ID token, just make an API call to `GET /Me`, which should include an `EmailAddress` property.

I'm reworking the tutorial on dev.outlook.com to do this.